# How can I avoid a Typescript Error, TS2345, in the Microsoft Bot Framework's StatePropertyAccessor when I assign a property

Tags: javascript, typescript, botframework, state

While building a bot in Typescript I am getting an error TS2345 error with Typescript version 3.7.2.  The error prevents me from creating properties on the fly, even if they are undefined, or even referring to them in the `stateProperty` accessor.

In the [javascript example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/45.state-management/bots/stateManagementBot.js) this is accomplished with the following code without error.

```js
this.conversationDataAccessor = conversationState.createProperty(CONVERSATION_DATA_PROPERTY);
        this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);

        // The state management objects for the conversation and user state.
        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.userState = userState;

        this.onMessage(async (turnContext, next) => {
            // Get the state properties from the turn context.
            const userProfile = await this.userProfileAccessor.get(turnContext, {});
            const conversationData = await this.conversationDataAccessor.get(
                turnContext, { promptedForUserName: false });

            if (!userProfile.name) {
```

However, in Typescript I can't figure out a way to avoid the error.  I can use the state property directly and attach the property that way but I am not sure that is correct and or when exactly it is attaching to the object and or referring to the DB directly. In this case the DB in memory.  In effect it works but again, I am not sure I am on the correct object that would be the one referring to my state property accessor property i.e. `const CONVERSATION_DATA_PROPERTY = 'conversationData';`

With that said, when I access the userState directly which is Typed to `BotState` it does seem to persist through the turn context.

Another question, Is what type should I apply to the user state stateProperty accessor?

I have it set to `UserState` but I am not sure that is correct.  What should the userstate type be set to?

Here is the code example:

```js
this.dialogState = this.conversationState.createProperty<DialogState>('DialogState');
this.userProfileAccessor = this.userState.createProperty<UserState>('UserState');
```

****Update per changes below

I've added the changes as such based on the information from the answer below.

For the user profile and for conversation data I now add in the index.ts file 2 property accessors.

```js
let userProfileAccessor: StatePropertyAccessor<UserProfile>;
let dialogDataAccessor: StatePropertyAccessor<DialogData>;
```

below the state storage implementations I add in the property setters.

```js
dialogDataAccessor = conversationState.createProperty<DialogData>(DIALOG_DATA_PROPERTY);
userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty<UserProfile>(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);
```

I added in the dialog data property|DialogData separate from the Dialog State property because I need to access the properties separate from the dialogstate which contains the dialogstack of the conversation state.

Also, it allows me to have a typed dialog `StatePropertyAccessor` which the dialogstate doesn't allow for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would absolutely avoid accessing `UserState` or `DialgoState` directly using something like `this.userState.x.y.z = 'myNewData'`. I've seen this cause many, many issues and is why we use the `accessors`.

Your code example at the end is okay for `DialogState` but not for `UserState`. It's kind of a long answer why, but here it goes...

In `index.ts`, you [create `ConversationState` and `UserState`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/792e3ecb9938ec8800927621ca0281cc1d5b9c4b/samples/typescript_nodejs/13.core-bot/src/index.ts#L66). Those are classes in the BotFramework SDK that handle very specific tasks.

- [`ConversationState`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/2115012394877abcfc8234ebad43d09b9ac2d9d0/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/conversationState.ts#L19) isolates different conversations from each other in storage.
- [`UserState`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/userState.ts#L19) isolates different users' data from each other in storage
- They both extend [`BotState`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/2115012394877abcfc8234ebad43d09b9ac2d9d0/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/botState.ts#L39), which handles how those pieces of storage are actually stored and retrieved.
- You should never directly manipulate anything on these because the Bot Framework depends on the properties of each of these.

So...the reason that your code example is "wrong" is because you have:

```js
this.userState.createProperty<UserState>('UserState');
```

...which tells the bot to create an additional `UserState` object within the existing `UserState` object. That "works", but since [`UserState`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-core/src/userState.ts) doesn't actually have any properties, TypeScript has no idea what keys and values you want to store in there.

In TypeScript, you're probably seeing errors when using something like this:

```js
const userProfile = await this.userProfileAccessor.get(turnContext, {});
const conversationData = await this.conversationDataAccessor.get(
                turnContext, { promptedForUserName: false });
```

because you haven't defined what type those objects are supposed to be. You'd need something like

```js
export interface UserProfile {
    name: string;
    data: {
        age: number;
        location: string;
    }
}

[...]
this.userState.createProperty<UserProfile>('UserProfile');
const userProfile: UserProfile = await this.userProfileAccessor.get(turnContext, {});
```

...or something similar.

Note: You should also make sure that you keep names consistent. For example, if you're using `createProperty('UserProfile')`, you should name the variable `userProfile` when retrieving it. Also note that the ``` 'UserProfile`` string just tells ```createProperty`to create an object in`UserState`with the key name of "UserProfile", so the object would look something like:`UserState: { ...UserProfile: {} }`

---

I'm relatively sure this both addresses all of your issues and provides a fix for them. If not, add some code to your question and I'll provide additional help.

Comment: Thank you. I have found one other thing I will update in my question that you could answer would be awesome.  The question is this.  when accessing the accessor from another dialog, lets say down the waterfall, and I want to use the userProfileAccessor which will be typed to the StatePropertyAccessor<UserProfile>, as you said previously, will I now have access to the state properties accessor without getting a `get` undefined error?  The error happens unless I reuse the this.userProfileAccessor = this.userState.createProperty... property in the constructor?

Comment: so yea the error is the same. Let me explain exactly what I am doing and you can tell me if this is the case.

It seems that I need to set the creatproperty in every constructor I want to either use and or edit a property via the stateproperty accessor.  Is this the case:  here is an example: `this.userProfileAccessor = this.userState.createProperty<UserProfile>('ProfileState');`

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Ah. I see what you mean. This can be solved by declaring your `userProfileAccessor` in more of a root dialog and then passing it to the constructor for each dialog--you'll need to edit the constructor from something like `constructor(conversationState, userState)` to something like `constructor(userProfileAccessor)`

Comment: that's what I thought... let me think about that one and see what I come up with. but the same would have to be done for the dialog state

Comment: so anything that falls below the root but still a dialog i.e. the dialogbot or the welcomedialogbot I would still need to establish the statepropertyacessor as I described?  If that makes sense

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Not necessarily. You could instantiate the accessors in `index.ts`, then pass them into any dialog or activityHandler constructor. After instantiating them, you pass them [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/typescript_nodejs/13.core-bot/src/index.ts#L79), and just make sure to also add an argument to the class constructors .

Comment: als0 @mdricheardson you've been a big help I am going to post one more thing about creating an adapter for a custom state storage such as redis or something else. I want to mimic the cosmos db adapter for nodejs.  Keep a look out if you can help :D

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Will do. We distribute support tickets at 9am PST every work day, so if it has the `botframework` tag, I'll see it. I'm probably a good person on the support team to take custom storage tickets, too.

Comment: ok as I circle back around to dialog state this is where I am at.  I have the conversationstate set as previously described as 'DialogState.'  The issue now is the very same thing that the interface of DialogState doesn't allow for for anything except fo the dialogstack[].  So either I would need to create a separate dialog state property and not use the DialogState type interface or override it.  What is the preferred solution here?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew I'm not sure what you mean, but if you open a new SO ticket and include your code, I'm sure I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: basically i need to add custom properties to the conversation state... Again, this is tied to the type of DialogState and only includes dialogStack as the interface property

Comment: ok sorry for drawing these comments out here.  So what I have done is split the conversation dialog to have it's own property different than the one associated to the this.dialogState i.e. <DialogState>.  This way it leaves that dialogstate alone, which I am assuming is proper for the dialog turn conversations and provides another property to access where I need it.  This new property is also on the root level with the user profile.  Here is an output example: { DialogState: { dialogStack: [ [Object] ] },
  eTag: '1',
  DialogData: { data: 'Christian data is here' } } < does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this code on the line above the line throwing an error?

```
//@ts-ignore
```

Comment: thank you that works. Also me, wondering why it's not working